# How to install React native app on iPhone locally without using Expo app?

Tags: react-native

Can we run React native app on Iphone locally without using Expo App ? In android native app development ,we can create .apk file and run locally on every android device using it. Is there any way to create such file in react native to install locally on iPhone

Comment: yes, you can export to ipa from Xcode.  It will need to be signed to install on a device.

Comment: can you please give me little more details